# matplotlib histtype='step' with logarithmic binning loses data

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm running python version 2.7.2 (IPython, if it makes a difference)
I'm trying to create some histograms with histtype step and logarithmic binning, but it's appearing to remove data points at 1. I'm setting ylim(ymin=0.1) as other posters in a similar question had suggested but that isn't seeming to help.

Here's a minimal example with the problem:

```
pl.hist([1,3,3],log=True, bins=pl.logspace(0,1,10));

pl.ylim(ymin=0.1)
```

gives an output 
as shown here (Note bars at 1 and 3 as expected)
[image]

If I now try

```
pl.hist([1,3,3], histtype='step');

pl.ylim(ymin=0.1)
```

I get an output as shown here (Once again all seems fine):
[image]

BUT, if I use both histtype='step' and logarithmic binning,

```
pl.hist([1,3,3],log=True, bins=pl.logspace(0,1,10),histtype='step');

pl.ylim(ymin=0.1)
```

it goes crazy, and I get this (Clearly missing data around 1):
[image].

What is going on? It's driving me crazy! Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. - Sorry for the bad image link formatting. I don't have enough reputation to be able to put in more than one link. Could someone with more reputation edit this?

Comment: What is your version of matplotlib?  Your last example works okay for me.

Comment: How do I see the version of matplotlib? I only know how to check my python version

Comment: Do `import matplotlib` and then `print matplotlib.__version__`.

Comment: Okay, a quick google search told me how to do that. I'm on matplotlib version '1.1.0'

Comment: That is a rather old version.  Try upgrading your version of matplotlib.

Comment: I never realized that I would have to upgrade matplotlib seperately. I'm kinda new to this. Does `sudo apt-get install matplotlib` do the job? I'm on Ubuntu

Comment: It may.  How to upgrade it depends on how it was initially installed.  If you start to have issues with upgrading it you should ask a separate question, as that's really a separate issue from what you've asked here.

Comment: Sure. If that was the problem, what answer to I select to mark as answered?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I removed the answer. The code works for me on mpl v 1.4.3 and 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a bug because of the old version of matplotlib that I was running. No problem observed in matplotlib version 1.5.1